# PHP - how to use $timestamp to check if today is Monday or 1st of the month?

Tags: php, timestamp

I have been looking through examples online, and I am finding them a bit cryptic or overkill.

What I need to do is something like this:

```
$timestamp = time();
```

and then find out if the day is a Monday or a fist of the month?

I am sure it is possible, I am just not sure how to do that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: you nedd to query data according to Monday or 1st or just to find out is it 1st or Monday? ;)

Comment: @Xfile I just need to know if today is monday? And in a seperate line I need to know if today is first of the month.  Essentially there are reminders that need to be sent weekly and monthly so that is why I need those.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Actually, you don't need timestamp variable because:

Exerpt from [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of php.net:

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using
>   the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is
>   given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value
>   of time().

```
if(date('j', $timestamp) === '1') 
    echo "It is the first day of the month today\n";

if(date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon') 
    echo "It is Monday today\n";
```

Comment: `if(date('w', $timestamp) === '1')` is better.

Comment: why is it better? explain. 'D' format character is more human readable.

Comment: I think in certain locale the result of `date('D')` can be Monday but not read as `'Mon'`. moreover, your code don't really care if it's human readable, it wants to react the correct way if it's monday or not.

Answer (score 8):

This should solve it:

```
$day = date('D');
$date = date('d')
if($day == Mon){
    //Code for monday
}
if($date == 01){
    //code for 1st fo the month
}
else{
    //not the first, no money for you =/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will grab.. Monday from mysql

```
$monday = 1; //tuesday= 2.. sunday = 7

    AND $monday = (date_format(from_unixtime(your_date_column),'%w'))
```

OR days..

```
$day = 1; ///1st in month

    AND $day = (date_format(from_unixtime(your_date_column),'%d'))
```

JUST TO KNOW

```
$date  = date("d"); //1st?
$dayinweek = date("w"); //monday? //as a number in a week what you need more then just "Monday" I guess..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$firstdaymonth = strtotime('first day this month');
```

Comment: sorry, little bit confused, how can I enter 'first day this month' into that function?

Comment: by writing literally `'first day this month'`. strtotime accepts those. google it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Because $date can monday or sunday. Should be check it**

```
public function getWeek($date){
    $date_stamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));

     //check date is sunday or monday
    $stamp = date('l', $date_stamp);      

    if($stamp == 'Mon'){
        $week_start = $date;
    }else{
        $week_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Last Monday', $date_stamp));
    }


    if($stamp == 'Sunday'){
        $week_end = $date;
    }else{
        $week_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Next Sunday', $date_stamp));
    }        
    return array($week_start, $week_end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **PHP >= 5.1** it is possible to use `date('N')`, which returns an ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week, where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday.

So you can do

```
if(date('N', $timestamp) === '1' || date('j', $timestamp) === '1')) {
    echo "Today it is Monday OR the first of the month";
}
```