# Find if a given date is the first monday of the month

Tags: php, function, date, datetime

trying to pass in some validation to check if a given date is the first monday of the month, if it is then do something if not do something else. So far I have come up with this to check the day of week given a date but dont know how to check if it is the first monday of the month, preferably I would like to make this a function.

```
$first_day_of_week = date('l', strtotime('9/2/2013'));
// returns Monday
```

Comment: Check out [Getting first weekday in a month with strtotime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357490/getting-first-weekday-in-a-month-with-strtotime), here on SO!

Comment: Kindly refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063336/php-how-to-use-timestamp-to-check-if-today-is-monday-or-1st-of-the-month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$first_day_of_week = date('l', strtotime('9/2/2013'));
$date = intval(date('j', strtotime('9/2/2013')));
if ($date <= 7 && $first_day_of_week == 'Monday') {
    // It's the first Monday of the month.
}
```

It seems kind of asinine, I know, but it allows you to replace `'9/2/2013'` with a variable if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes to do this very easily:-

```
/**
 * Check if a given date is the first Monday of the month
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return bool
 */
function isFirstMondayOfMonth(\DateTime $date)
{
    return (int)$date->format('d') <= 7 && $date->format('l') === 'Monday';
}

$day = new \DateTime('2013/9/2');
var_dump(isFirstMondayOfMonth($day));

$day = new \DateTime('2013/10/2');
var_dump(isFirstMondayOfMonth($day));
```

See it [working](http://3v4l.org/25nns).